# Preliminary server check for updated webpage(s) in HTML

Tags: html

I am having difficulty finding a successful way to implement an HTTP header that more or less says:

> > > This webpage has been updated so do not cache until after it has gone back to the server<<<

I have looked online and think that the best way to go about this is using the **Last-Modified** header. I am just having trouble with the logic behind doing so.

This should be a helpful tool for multiple people who are constantly updating a website/webpages so their clients who visit regularly do not see the cached version of their site but rather the updated version.

Thanks in advance.

-Justin

Comment: As a side note, you can reply with a `304 Not Modified` to show that the requested object was not modified since the last request. See the following RFC for more info: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you Polynomial.